# I have a list where I want each element of the list to be in as a single row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of lists and I want to assign each of the lists to a specific column, I have created the columns of the Dataframe. But in each column, the elements are coming as a list. I want each element of this list to be a separate row as part of that particular column.

Here's what I did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.array(dataset).T],columns=list1) 

print(df)
```

Attached screenshot for the output. 
[image: 1]

I want each element of that list to be a row, as my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

Fasteners = ['Screws & Bolts', 'Threaded Rods & Studs', 'Eyebolts', 'U-Bolts']
Adhesives_and_Tape = ['Adhesives','Tape','Hook & Loop']
Weld_Braz_Sold = ['Electrodes & Wire','Gas Regulators','Welding Gloves','Welding Helmets & Glasses','Protective Screens']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fastener': pd.Series(Fasteners), 'Adhesives_and_Tape': pd.Series(Adhesives_and_Tape), 'Weld_Braz_Sold': pd.Series(Weld_Braz_Sold)})

print(df)
```

Please provide the structure of the database you are starting from or the structure of the respective lists. I can give you are more focussed answer to your specific problem then.

If the structure is getting larger, you can also iterate through all lists when generating the data frame. This is just the basic process to solve your question.

Feel free to comment for further help.

**EDIT**

If you want to loop through a database of lists. Use the following code additionally:

```
for i in range(len(list1)): df.iloc[:,i] = pd.Series(dataset[i])
```

Comment: Hey @Sumit chatterjee, please accept my answer, if it solved your problem at hand. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for your help! But I can't use this as this requirement is dynamic in nature, i.e. I need to run this code for many more dataset which won't be the same as I gave above. I have attached the screenshot for the data structure that I am looking for.

Comment: Fasteners          Adhesives & Tape          Welding, Brazing & Soldering
DDDD                 XXXX                            AAAA
EEEE                 BBBB                                LLLL
FFFF                       gggggg                              IIOIO

Something like this!

Comment: So you need a solution where you iterate throuout all lists availabe?

Comment: Correct! I tried looping through the list but my value and indexes are not matching, looking to solve this now. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: It worked!, I looped throught the list and made the remaining ones as a pandas series. Here goes my code: 

for i in range(len(list1)):
          df.iloc[:,i] = pd.Series(dataset[i])